# Why does the following method shows error of return type

Tags: java, methods, return

```
public static int letterPosition(String word,char a)//returns the position of searched character
{

    int lenght=word.length();

    for (int i=0; i < lenght; i++)
    {

        if(word.charAt(i)==a)
        {
            return i;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't handle the case where the character was never found.

Comment: There are three answers below, were any of these any use? Please consider accepting one of them as the answer, if so - to do so, click the tick mark adjacent to the most useful one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the possibility that the loop isn't entered (or if it is entered, that the character isn't found). Add something like

```
return -1;
```

at the end of the method (to handle when the character isn't present).

Answer (score 2):

Something must be returned, and your return statement is inside the 'if' statement, implying you have to enter the conditional statement to return something. You need to have a return option if the 'if' statement isn't executed.

You can fix this by adding an 'else if' statement after the 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

please do something like,

```
public static int letterPosition(String word,char a)//returns the position of searched character
{
    int returnValue = -1;
    if(word != null){ //this will save us from NullPointerException...

    int lenght=word.length();

    for (int i=0; i < lenght; i++)
    {

        if(word.charAt(i)==a)
        {
            returnValue  = i;
            break;
        }

    } //end of for loop
  }//end of if - word != null 
  return returnValue;
}
```